# How to output logarithm of some calculated value using Django, MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, aggregate-functions

I want to create the following query in Django:

```
select field1, count(field1), log(count(field1)) from object_table
where parent_id = 12345
group by field1;
```

I've implemented `field1, count(field1)` and `group by field1` by following:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Object.objects.filter(
    parent = 12345
).values_list(
    'field1'
).annotate(
    count=Count('field1')
)
```

However if I add something like this

```
.extra(
    select={'_log':'log(count)'}
)
```

it doesn't affect my results. Could you give me a clue what am I doing wrong? How to implement `log(count(field))` within Django?

PS, I'm using Django 1.9.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that some databases don't natively support logarithm function (e.g. sqlite). This is probably an operation that should be done in your Python code instead of the database query.

```
import math

for obj in object_list:
    # use math.log() for natural logarithm
    obj._log = math.log10(obj.count)
```

If you are certain you can rely on a database function and you want to use the database to perform the computation, you can use raw queries. For example, postgres has the log function implemented:

```
query = """\
select count(field1), log(count(field1)) as logvalue 
from myapp_mymodel 
group by field1"""

queryset = MyModel.objects.raw(query)
for obj in queryset:
    print(obj.logvalue)
```

Comment: Yeah, I spent almost day digging this and it seems that it is a way to go. Thanks!